# Convert argb to string

Tags: winforms, powershell

Which method allows convert ARGB to string as `'int, int, int'`? Example. The `$Main` background color is set as a string `'0, 100, 200'`. Return `$Main.BackColor` gives ARGB but not string '0, 100, 200':

```
$Main  = [System.Windows.Forms.Form] @{
    BackColor = '0, 100, 200'
}

$Main.BackColor
--------------
R             : 0
G             : 100
B             : 200
A             : 255
IsKnownColor  : False
IsEmpty       : False
IsNamedColor  : False
IsSystemColor : False
Name          : ff0064c8
```

The `To.String()` method returns the result `Color [A=255, R=0, G=100, B=200]`
. This is not what is expected.

At the moment I am doing this:

```
 ('R', 'G', 'B').ForEach({ $Main.BackColor.$_ }) -join ', '

--------------
0, 100, 200
```

However, I hope that there are special methods for converting as `ARGB` to `string`, as `string` to `ARGB`. What are these methods? Thanks

Comment: Is it important that you can serialize it as a readable string? There's no built-in string method that works both ways, but you can convert the color to a single `[int]` and back again if that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some nice and initiative answers for this question, but it looks like all have overlooked the *correct way*, using type converters. There is a [`ColorConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.colorconverter?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) responsible for `ConvertTo` and `ConvertFrom` String/Color:

```
$Color = [System.Drawing.Color]'0, 100, 200'
[System.Drawing.ColorConverter]::new().ConvertToString($Color)
# Result: 0, 100, 200
```

This is the same class which is used by `PropertyGrid` to convert the string to `Color` or `Color` and vice versa.

It will take care of `A` element of the color as well, for example if you create the color like `100, 0, 100, 200`. This solution automatically include or ignore  `A` portion whenever is required:

```
$Color = [System.Drawing.Color]'100, 0, 100, 200'
[System.Drawing.ColorConverter]::new().ConvertToString($Color)
# Result: 100, 0, 100, 200
```

Comment: A bit late to the party, but it's worth to mention it's the correct way in fact. `TypeConverter` is used by `PropertyGrid` to convert the `string` to `Color` or `Color` to `string` as well. It will take care of `A` element of the color as well, for example if you create the color like `100, 0, 100, 200`, then all the custom solutions in other answers will ignore `A` element in the `string` representation, but this solution automatically ignore it or include it whenever is required.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for.  You are not late for the party, you are just in time)

Comment: Well done. As an aside: Casting a string such as `'0, 100, 200'` to `[System.Drawing.Color]` in PowerShell works great in _Windows PowerShell_, but is currently broken in PowerShell [Core], as of v7.0 - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9863) - because the `[System.Drawing.ColorConverter]` type-converter attribute no longer being applied automatically; as of this writing, a fix is being considered for v7.1

Comment: @mklement0 Good point. In this case I expect to convert string to color using `[System.Drawing.ColorConverter]::new().ConvertFromString('0, 100, 200')`. Thanks for the feedback :)

Answer (score 5):

> However, I hope that there are special methods for converting as argb to string, as string to argb. What are these methods?

You'd think so, but to my knowledge there isn't a builtin two-way convertion for this, unfortunately.

Here are a couple of things you can do instead:

### Create your own `ConvertFrom-Color` function:

```
function ConvertFrom-Color
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [System.Drawing.Color[]]$InputColor
    )

    process {
        foreach($color in $InputColor){
            $color.R,$color.G,$color.B -join ', '
        }
    }
}
```

And use when needed:

```
PS C:\> $colorString = $Main.BackColor |ConvertFrom-Color
PS C:\> $colorString
0, 100, 200
```

---

### Use an `[int]`

An `ARGB` color consists of 4 1-byte channels, which fits perfectly into a 32-bit integer. If you need to communicate a distinct color using a single argument, this is already supported:

```
PS C:\> $color = [System.Drawing.Color]'0,100,100'
PS C:\> $color.ToArgb()
-16751516
PS C:\> $argbValue = $color.ToArgb()
PS C:\> [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb($argbValue)

R             : 0
G             : 100
B             : 100
A             : 255
IsKnownColor  : False
IsEmpty       : False
IsNamedColor  : False
IsSystemColor : False
Name          : ff006464
```

Just like with your initial string representation, it's worth highlighting that converting from the `[int]` representation works both with explicit casts and implicit conversions when assigning to typed properties:

```
$argbValue = -16751516
# This works just fine
[System.Drawing.Color]$argbValue
# As does this
[System.Windows.Forms.Form]@{ BackColor = $argbValue }
```

---

### Override [`Color.ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.tostring?view=netframework-4.8)

Since you're interested in changing the behavior of the default string representation of `System.Drawing.Color`, you might as well override the `ToString()` method implementation:

```
Update-TypeData -TypeName System.Drawing.Color -MemberType ScriptMethod -MemberName ToString -Value {
    $this.psobject.Properties['R','G','B'].Value -join ', '
} -Force
```

Now all instances of `[System.Drawing.Color]` will use your custom `ToString()` method when converted to a string:

```
PS C:\> "$($Main.BackColor)"
0, 100, 200
```

Comment: Thank you for the information.  Please note, @Reza Aghaei shared a great method.  I hope this information is useful to you.

Answer (score 3):

[Reza Aghaei's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60293473/45375) shows the proper solution and [Mathias R. Jessen's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60283632/45375) shows robust alternatives.

Let me complement them with a *pragmatic hack*; while deriving serializable representations from *for-display* strings (`.ToString()`) is generally ill-advised, the format at hand is unlikely to change in a way that will break this:

```
PS> $Main.BackColor -replace '[^\d,]'  # remove all chars. except digits and commas
255,0,100,200
```

Note: The above includes the alpha value, unlike the original input string; however, casting back to `[System.Drawing.Color]` works equally well.

Comment: "a pragmatic hack", I love it, hahaha <3

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no custom string format in System.Drawing.Color. You need custom conversion. You can use your method or any other. I would use custom expression and string interpolation:

```
$c = [System.Drawing.Color]'0, 100, 200'

#simulate array
$c,$c | select @{N="Color";E={"$($_.R), $($_.G), $($_.B)"}}
```

**Result:**

```
Color      
-----      
0, 100, 200
0, 100, 200
```

Comment: Thank you for the information.  Please note, @Reza Aghaei shared a great method.  I hope this information is useful to you.